# converting strings to integers by using "stringstream "

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert strings of data  to integers, (to use it for some calculations  ) by using `stringstream` , but it fails when there is a space.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    vector <string>data;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++) {
        getline(cin,line);
        data.push_back(line);
    }

    ///converting digits to int
    vector<int> values;
    int n;
    char ch=',';
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size();i++) {     
        stringstream stream(data[i]);

        while( stream >>n ) {
            if(stream >> ch) {
                values.push_back(n);
            }
            else {
                values.push_back(n);
            }
            cout<<n<<" ";
         }
         cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

input : `1,182,08 51 15`   -->   output : `1 182 8 1 5`
there are some digits lost after spaces.
so, what can I do to avoid it?

Comment: But if I strip spaces it will converts the whole string to one integer not 5 integers.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: 1, 182, ***08 or 8***, 51, 15 ?

Comment: the input is 1,182,08 51 15 and the expected output                                           is 1 182 8 51 15  ... not  1 182 8 1 5

Comment: seccpur's code works when completed.
Output: 1
182
8
51
15

Answer (score 0):

Complete working code based on seccpur's answer. Visual Studio 2017 Community:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

#define BUFSZ 100 // Set max size of the numbers as a single string
int convertToIntegers(char *s, vector<int> &values);

int main()
{
    int count;
    int i;
    char data[BUFSZ];
    vector<int> values;

    strcpy_s(data, "1,182,08 51 15");
    count = convertToIntegers(data, values);

//  for (auto val : values) // Show the result
//      cout << val << '\n';
// *** OR ***
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        cout << values[i] << '\n';

}
//////////////////////////////////////
// Convert a C string to integers
//
int convertToIntegers(char *s, vector<int> &values)
{
    vector<string> numbers;
    char *next_token;

    char* ptr = strtok_s(s, " -.,;", &next_token);
    while (ptr)
    {
        string str(ptr);
        numbers.push_back(str);
        ptr = strtok_s(NULL, " -.,;", &next_token); // Next number
    }
    //
    // Convert the resulting strings to integers
    //
    for (auto str : numbers)
        values.push_back(stoi(str));
    return (int)values.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know you have exactly one character as a separator, either a space, either a comma, the following code will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
string line;
vector <string>data;

for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++) {
    getline(cin,line);
    data.push_back(line);
}

///converting digits to int
vector<int> values;
int n;
char ch=',';
for (int i = 0; i < data.size();i++) {     
    stringstream stream(data[i]);

    while( stream >>n ) {
        char c = stream.get();
        //if(stream >> ch) {
        //    values.push_back(n);
        //}
        //else {
            values.push_back(n);
        //}
        cout<<n<<" ";
     }
     cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You are using multiple delimiters in the input ( like whitespace : , ; -) which complicates the matter. Here's a possible snippet using `std::strtok`:

```
    //Enter a line 
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);

    // Convert string to char* so that std::strtok could be used later
    char *cstr = new char[line.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(cstr, line.c_str());
    vector<string> words;

    // split line into multiple strings using multiple delimiters
    char* ptr = std::strtok(cstr, " -.,;");
    while (ptr)
    {
        string str(ptr);
        words.push_back(str);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " -.,;");
    }
    delete[] cstr;

    // Convert string to int
    vector<int> values;
    for (auto str : words){
        values.push_back(std::stoi(str));
    }
    // Print the values
    for (auto val : values){
        cout << val << '\n';
    }
```

Comment: I am a beginner in c++ , so I don‘t know what are the uses of std::strtok  and  unfortunately I can't understand the code.

Comment: Your input : 1,182,08 51 15 used spaces and commas, which are called delimiters. To split them into individual strings, we use std::strtok ( it is used to split string into tokens and it can take multiple delimiters). For single delimiter stringstream with getline() is good enough.